# Node.js require multiple files in the same folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm building a discord bot with node.js for my server and I have a bunch of commands for the bot. Each command is in a different file so I have a lot of `const cmd = require("../commands/cmd.js");`

```js
const kick = require("../commands/kick");
const info = require("../commands/info"); 
const cooldown = require("../commands/cooldown");
const help = require("../commands/help");
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside folder `commands` put a file called `index.js`.

Each time you implement new commands in new file, require that file in `index.js` and then add it to the exports of it. For example index.js would be:

```js
const kick = require('./kick');
const info = require('./info');

module.exports = {
  kick: kick,
  info: info
}
```

And then from any folder you can require multiple commands in one line like this:

```js
const { kick, info } = require('../commands');
```

Comment: Are you aware of any best-practices to automate this process? Let's say iterating over all the files in the directory (except `index.js`) and then including them in the `modules.exports` definition?

Answer (score 1):

Export an object from one file instead?

```
const kick = require("../commands/kick");
const info = require("../commands/info"); 
const cooldown = require("../commands/cooldown");
const help = require("../commands/help");

const commands = {
  kick,
  info,
  ...
}

module.exports = commands;
```

And then:

```
const commands = require('mycommands')

commands.kick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `index.js` file inside the `command` folder and then you can export an object like this.

```
const kick = require("../commands/kick");
const info = require("../commands/info"); 
const cooldown = require("../commands/cooldown");
const help = require("../commands/help");

const command = {
  kick,
  info,
  cooldown,
  help
};

module.exports = command;
```

You can import and use it like this:

```
const {kick, info} = require('./commands');
```